# Tabulator V4 - getData on form submit

Tags: tabulator

Having a dumb, I think. What's the v4 version of this:

```
var table = $("#eventsGrid");
var events = table.getData;
```

where #eventsGrid is a populated Tabulator.

Basically on submitting a form I want to grab all of the data in a Tabulator instance.

TIA,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

When you initially define a Tabulator it returns the object to use for this

```
var table = new Tabulator("#eventsGrid", {... your setup options ...});
```

You then use this variable to call functions on

```
var events = table.getData();
```

You can't look it up by selector like jQuery

There is a conversion guide for migrating from 3.5 to 4.0 here:
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.0/upgrade

Comment: Thanks Oli but it didn't work - throws an undefined error - but it did point me in the right direction. The table variable was defined in document ready so wasn't available in the onsubmit function.

Simply declared the variable outside & before document ready & voila!

Told you I was having a dumb :-D

Thanks!